# [ROS2] Start rosbag2 recording from launch file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

With the

```
ros2 bag record
```

command I can easily start recording data to a bag file. Is it possible the start recording in with a launch file? I would like to start some nodes from this launch file and start recording, as well.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341710/%5Bros2%5D-start-rosbag2-recording-from-launch-file/) by [tlaci](https://answers.ros.org/users/49859/tlaci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to launch the `ros2 bag record` command as an executable. For example, recording all topics:

```
import launch


def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'bag', 'record', '-a'],
            output='screen'
        )
    ])
```

and the XML equivalent if you are using ROS Eloquent or newer:

```
<launch>
  <executable cmd="ros2 bag record -a" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justinberi](https://answers.ros.org/users/74109/justinberi/) on 2021-05-25**:
Is anyone else experiencing an issue with this? When I ctrl-c the launch bag always dies.

The launch file:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
    ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ros2', 'bag', 'record', '-a'], output='screen', log_cmd=True),
])
```

On ctrl-c:

```
[ERROR] [ros2-2]: process has died [pid 40507, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 bag record -a'].
```

And the tables in the sqlite database seem corrupt.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-25**:
@justinberi I think that better place to ask for it would be a GitHub issue there: https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2 You can prepare your MWE and error description etc. and maybe get answers directly from maintainers